# Using resources of try-with-resources outside try

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream, socketchannel, try-with-resources

I'm using `SocketChannel` to send message between a server and a client. Once a client connects with a server, the server opens the `InputStreams` and `OutputStream` in a try-with-resources try, to receive messages **from** the client and send messages **to** the client, like so:

```
try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {}
```

I want to access `out` outside of the try. The try contains a while loop that repeatedly checks if messages has arrived on `in`, which works fine.

I tried setting a global variable, say `global_out`, by doing:

```
ObjectOutputStream global_out;
...
try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {

    setOut(out);
    while(should_check) {
        Object message = in.readObject();   
        //do something
    }
}
```

And then I tried writing to this OutputStream, like so:

```
public void sendMessage(Object message) {
    global_out.writeObject(message);
}
```

I only call `sendMessage(Object)` when `should_ceck` is `true` and test if `global_out` is `null`, which it isn't. However, `sendMessage(Object)` never returns. If `global_out` **isn't** `null`, it must have been set to something, so why can't the resources be used before the `try-with-resources` terminates?

Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: I don't see all this having anything to do with try-with-resources. You have an issue with the `write` call blocking. BTW there is no method `write(Object)` in `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik change to writeObject(Object). I assumed it has to do with try-with-catch, because if I `out.writeObject(Object)` inside of the try, it doesn't block and the message is sent. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is sendMessage being called from?  Is it being called synchronously from within the try block?  Asynchronously?  In general, it's pointless and dangerous to leak a reference to a resource opened in a try-with-resources statement, because the resource is only open while the try block is executing anyway (at the end of the statement, the resources are closed; that's the whole point of the statement).  So as global_out is only in a valid state within the execution scope of the try block, why do you need access to it outside of the scope?  What's the goal?

Comment: @MarkPeters I think the goal is clear: OP doesn't want to tediously pass that stream around to all methods. Basically, what he wants is *dynamic scope* for the stream.

Comment: @Ian2thedv When you move the call to within try, you have also changed the timing of that write. There may be something about other intervening code which causes blocking.

Comment: sendMessage is called from outside the try block, ansynchronously. Nothing in the try touches `out`.@MarkPeters The point? For every client connected to the server, a client-object is created, that stores the socket, inputstreams, outputstreams and the rest of the client details. The try-with-resources, which is inside a Thread, contained in the client-object, opens the needed resources, checks for incomming messages and closes the resources after the client disconnects. sendMessage is a method of the client-object. So messages can be sent to which ever client.